# Magento can not update html head

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add this code to my backend>design>html head>Miscellaneous Scripts but I get a 400 bad request error. I have tried refreshing catchy/deleting var folder

This is the code `<meta property="og:image" content="http://link.com" />`

I can put random text in the Miscellaneous Scripts field and it will save but not the above code. Can not figure out why.

I am on magento 1.8.1.0 and using a content delivery network. Not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: You need to change this link `http://link.com`  by a image link. Maybe it is the reason.

Comment: Also don't forget to clear your cache before test the solution.

Comment: I did use an actual link, but it still did not work.